# OrientDB ALTER PROPERTY affects super class and all other descendant classes?

Tags: orientdb

I was experimenting with inheritance with 2.1.16 and noticed when ALTER PROPERTY is used on a child class to alter an inherited property, the schema is altered for the superclass and all descendants of that superclass.  In the following example, B extends A.  C extends A.  B alters mandatory/notnull for a property inherited from A.  The schema change impacts A, B, and C.

Is this the expected behavior for altering inherited properties (at least as far as mandatory/notnull are concerned)?  If so, is there an approach for making child classes more/less restrictive or is it intentional the class schema will be identical across all inherited child classes?

Result below is identical regardless of whether A is abstract or not.

```
CREATE CLASS A Extends V ABSTRACT;
CREATE PROPERTY A.Name STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY A.Description STRING;

CREATE CLASS B Extends A ;
ALTER PROPERTY B.Name MANDATORY TRUE;
ALTER PROPERTY B.Name NOTNULL TRUE;

CREATE CLASS C Extends A ;

CREATE VERTEX C CONTENT { "Description": "Hello" };
```

Yields the following message even though C extends A, not B:

```
The field 'A.Name' is mandatory, but not found on record: C{Description:Hello}
```

with class properties showing mandatory/notnull true for all three Name properties:

```
CLASS 'A'...

PROPERTIES
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 NAME                          | TYPE        | LINKED TYPE/CLASS             | MANDATORY | READONLY | NOT NULL |    MIN    |    MAX    | COLLATE  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 Name                          | STRING      | null                          | true      | false    | true     |           |           | default  |
 Description                   | STRING      | null                          | false     | false    | false    |           |           | default  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
orientdb {db=AdvRepos}> info class B

CLASS 'B'...

PROPERTIES
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 NAME                          | TYPE        | LINKED TYPE/CLASS             | MANDATORY | READONLY | NOT NULL |    MIN    |    MAX    | COLLATE  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 Name                          | STRING      | null                          | true      | false    | true     |           |           | default  |
 Description                   | STRING      | null                          | false     | false    | false    |           |           | default  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
orientdb {db=AdvRepos}> info class C

CLASS 'C'...


PROPERTIES
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 NAME                          | TYPE        | LINKED TYPE/CLASS             | MANDATORY | READONLY | NOT NULL |    MIN    |    MAX    | COLLATE  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
 Name                          | STRING      | null                          | true      | false    | true     |           |           | default  |
 Description                   | STRING      | null                          | false     | false    | false    |           |           | default  |
-------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi David, can you open an issue on github ?

Comment: Done. Thanks. https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6088